# How to blacklist an Ethereum address to trade on a decentralised exchange?

Tags: uniswap, pancakeswap, decentralized-exchange

How to blacklist a particular token to trade on a decentralised exchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from there that UniSwap contract uses the `transferFrom` method to take users tokens and exchange them. As we know `transferFrom` works only if you've previously approved particular address or contract to manage your tokens. So now you need to include a blacklist logic inside the `transferFrom` method:

**1. First create a mapping which is going to store the blacklisted addresses:**

```
mapping (address => bool) blacklist;
```

**2. Add logic only for the ERC20 contract owner to manage the blacklist:**

```
function addRemoveBlacklist(address _address) public onlyOwner {
    require(address(_address) != address(0), "Address is not valid");  
    if (blacklist[_address]) {
        blacklist[_address] = false;
    } else {
        blacklist[_address] = true;
    }
}
```

**3. Then at the very top of the `transferFrom` method you can add the following condition:**

```
require(!blacklist[_address], "Address is blacklisted.");
```

This condition will stop users from executing UniSwap swaps even if they've previously approved the UniSwap smart contract to manage their tokens.

But this logic is not stopping the blacklisted address to transfer his tokens into completely new address and still execute the swap. If you want to cover this case also then add the `require(!blacklist[_address], "Address is blacklisted.");` condition at the top of the `transfer` method also so blacklisted addresses won't be able to move their tokens at all.

Comment: How to do if i have a existing token and this logic is not implemented in that token ?

Comment: Absolutely nothing and this is why UniSwap is called **decentralized** exchange.